# Webapi Update Multiple Records

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

Which is the best approach for updating multiple records at a time using ASP.NET Web API and OData against an Entity Framework database?

Let's suppose we have a table in our database with a "State" field, and we want to do something similar to this SQL statement: "UPDATE Table set State = 1". Should I do a loop with GET and PUT for each record? I do not like it at all, I guess it must be a better way to accomplish this.

Thank you

Comment: Seems like less of an ASP.NET WebApi question and more something related to your data provider. What data provider are you using? Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes, Entity Framework. But I do not mean the internal develpment of the update, but if there is a way to avoid the loop of GET and PUT. Thank you

Comment: Maybe I have not explained well, sorry. I mean that as we have a GetAll method and we can filter it (with OData) to specify which records do we want, if there is a way to filter which ones we want to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can't do this natively in OData, but there is one approach that will definitely work; just use a native Web API action to perform the update.

E.g.

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("resources/state")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateState(int newState)
{
    db.Database.SqlCommand("UPDATE Table SET State = @p0", newState);
}
```

You'd call this from a client using a `PUT /resources/state?newState=1`.

It might be clearer to make `newState` an enum:

```
public enum State
{
    New = 0,
    Processed = 1,
    Error = 2,
    etc.
}

[HttpPut]
[Route("resources/state")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateState(State newState)
{
    db.Database.SqlCommand("UPDATE Table SET State = @p0", (int)newState);
}
```

Then your call becomes `PUT /resources/state?newState=Processed` which is a little clearer.

Comment: This os what I was looking for, a good approach to do that. Thank you, great answer

Answer (score 0):

OData supports such kinds of operations. You can use OData Action to update the state.

Blog: [odata-actions-and-functions](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions)

Sample: [ODataActionSample](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataActionsSample/)